# mail format change when received

Tags: linux, perl, bash, email, sendmail

I have file.out logfile which contain plain text and formated as

```
1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

2abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

3abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

<--------------------

4abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

5abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

My problem is when I received it in my mail box the format is changed

OUTPUT in MAILBOX

```
1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 2abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 3abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

<---------------

4abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

5abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

the first 1,2,3 is not supposed to be in a single line. while the 4,5,6 stays formated as is.

the file was originally sent by perl script using Mail:Sendmail module, but I also tried sending through mail command to test also.

`cat file.out | mail -s reportfile email@email.com` got the same result.
I've  also check the file and there is no extra spaces or characters.

Comment: what says `hexdump -C file.out`

Comment: What do you use to read the mail at the receiving end?

Comment: Agree with @DeVadder: Do you use Outlook? I've had this problem in the past, there's a setting for it where outlook removes what it thinks are "extra" newlines.

Comment: Yes I was using outlook2007, it's a mail client issue?

Comment: Very possible. This sure looks like the software on the sending site and the one on the receiving site disagreeing about where there are proper newlines. And Outlook has some strong opinions on how things should be formatted...

Comment: @DeVadder Got it. already resolved  the problem. it's outlook issue. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

MS Outlook 2007 issue. resolve it with this: go to Tools > Preferences > Email > Email-Options >Message handling > "Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages".